# Equivalence classes of an infinite relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I have the following equivalence relation:

$$
\begin{equation}
R=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \mid |x| = |y|\}
\end{equation}
$$

I have already verified its properties, but, as the set is infinite, I have no idea about how can I describe this relation's equivalence classes. How should I do it?

Comment: Why not try figure out the equivalence classes containing individual elements? For instance, what is the equivalence class containing $-1$? What about $2$? This might make the problem more clear.

Comment: almost all the equivalence classes contain precisely two elements.

Comment: $|x| = |y|$ holds if and only if $x=\pm y$ (follows from the definition of absolute value), so elements in the same class are same numbers up to multiple of $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, we describe the equivalence class of $x$ as the following set:

$$[x] = \{y \in \mathbb{Z}: (y,x) \in R\}$$

Let $x \neq 0$. Then, we can see that:

$$|x| = |-x|$$

In other words, $x \in [x]$ and $-x \in [x]$. These are going to be the only two elements of $[x]$. There is no other element that will satisfy $|x| = |y|$.

Now, that is going to hold for almost every equivalence class. Now, let $x = 0$. Then, we can see that:

$$|0| = |-0|$$

So, it follows that $0 \in [0]$ and that's it. The set $[0]$ contains no other elements of $\mathbb{Z}$. That completely describes the equivalence classes for this relation.